Value of type 'DeepLink' has no member 'getUrlParams'
I am trying to run a flutter project from VS Code, but there is a Value of type 'DeepLink' has no member 'getUrlParams' error.
I took a look at the DeepLink module from  here, (this is the package that the project is using), and I can see that the function getUrlParams is now commented, which I assume this function is no longer being used. However, I am not sure on what to update or the changes needed to be done.
Attached picture is how the project is using the DeepLink in the swift code.

Has anyone encountered this error before ? Thanks in advance !

try using the block of code that inside the getUrlParams() to your Swift.....Plugin class.
I think the URLQueryItem() class is not in the sdk, but since you have the commented code, you can remake the class with desired ids.

Are you asking how people would workaround the removal of the method?

hi @benc , yes. if other devs have faced this error, I would like to know the workaround. thank you.
